# problem in displaying an image

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to publish 10 images from my pictures folder..so that I added the link for that..code runs correctly but image is not displaying..

pub.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

    cv_bridge::CvImage cv_image;
    cv_image.image = cv::imread("/home/abi/Pictures/attachments/",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv_image.encoding = "bgr8";
    sensor_msgs::Image ros_image;
    cv_image.toImageMsg(ros_image);
 image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("/static_image/compressed", 3);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(5);

  while (nh.ok()) 
  {
    pub.publish(ros_image);
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}
```

sub.cpp:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
      {
    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, "bgr8");
         //ROS_INFO("Hi");
        cv::imshow("view", cv_ptr->image);
        cvNamedWindow("view",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
      }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
      {
    ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    return;
      }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  cvNamedWindow("view",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/static_image/", 1,imageCallback);
  ros::spin();
  cvDestroyWindow("view");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143916/problem-in-displaying-an-image/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You forgot to tell ros to "spin" in pub.cpp:

```
while (nh.ok()) 
 {
   pub.publish(ros_image);
   ros::spinOnce(); //Here is where the magic happens
   loop_rate.sleep();
 }
```

And I am not all that sure about your call to imread

```
cv::imread("/home/abi/Pictures/attachments/",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

You are passing a folder name instead of a path to an image. Should be something like

```
cv::imread("/home/abi/Pictures/attachments/someimage.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

**[UPDATE]**

Also, you are publishing the topic */static_image/compressed* but subscribing on the topic */static_image/*. Make sure that you are publishing what you think you are publishing. You can run the publisher node and then check the published topics with: *rostopic list*

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on 2014-03-25**:
thank you..But it didn't work..can you suggest some other option.. thank you.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-03-26**:
I have updated my answer, please check it out.

**Comment by [lilylily](https://answers.ros.org/users/12746/lilylily/) on 2014-03-30**:
will this has something to do with the compression. i use this image viewer to [load and display image](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/how-to-start/) in windows and on web. but i have never display static image before. so maybe it won't work

**Comment by [arronlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/5223/arronlee/) on 2014-05-11**:
Hi, lilylily.
How about building a [web-based image viewer](http://www.yiigo.com/guides/csharp/how-to-create-web-viewer.shtml) to help display images? Using code is too complicated for me. I prefer to ask some 3rd party [Imaging SDKs](http://www.yiigo.com/guides/csharp/) for help. It will be better if the imaging SDK is totally manual and can be customized by users according to our own favors. Any other suggestion?